Where is the extra data in my Product Version coming from?
I'm building a project through Azure Pipelines.  I'm not managing any version settings in VS -- I'm setting the version with dotnet build.
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'DotNet Build'
      inputs: 
       command: build
       arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) /p:Version=$(GitVersion.SemVer)'
       projects: $(ProjectPath)

As you can see, I set the Version using a GitVersion variable.  In the resulting .dll, the File Version shows the version correctly.  I expected the Product Version to show the same thing but it seems to include some additional weird guid or something.  Does anyone know where that comes from and how to keep it from being appended?


From your screenshot, the long string should be the commit hash.
The issue is from the .net8 SDK. It will include the commit SHA in the informational version automatically.
I can reproduce the same issue.

By default, Azure Pipelines will use .net8 to build the project now.
To solve this issue, you can add the <IncludeSourceRevisionInInformationalVersion>false</IncludeSourceRevisionInInformationalVersion> to your csproj file.
For example:
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IncludeSourceRevisionInInformationalVersion>false</IncludeSourceRevisionInInformationalVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

Or you can add the argument to your build task: /p:IncludeSourceRevisionInInformationalVersion=false
For example:
--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) /p:Version=$(GitVersion.SemVer) /p:IncludeSourceRevisionInInformationalVersion=false 

Or  you can downgrade the .net version with the task: Use .NET Core
For more detailed info, you can refer to this ticket: Git commit ID included in assembly ProductVersion field when building with sdk 8

My understanding is that Product Version (aka InformationalVersion) can contain any value.  Is there a way to explicitly set that via build task arguments or from within Azure Pipelines?

@RHarris Yes. You can add the argument: /p:IncludeSourceRevisionInInformationalVersion=false  to the dotnet build argument.

Sorry @kevin-lu-msft, In my comment,  I was asking if there is a way to explicitly set the actual value for InformationalVersion as opposed to just "turning it off" -- iow, can I force Informational Version to show something completely different than version?

I think it's documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.productversion?view=windowsdesktop-8.0 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyinformationalversionattribute?view=net-8.0

I suggest using Direcorty.Build.Props file to control build related properties.
